# Shortest path for a given waypoints

Tags: postgis, google-maps, php, postgresql

I have an application where the user selects some "markers" from a google maps (all those coordinates' markers are stored into a postgresql database).

Right now, I can draw the route between all selected markers (using DirectionService) but when I have over 10 waypoints the route seems to be drawn in the user selected order (not in the "shortest route" order - I also used `optimizeWaypoints` parameter to true and split the route into subroutes of 8 points + start and stop points without success).
What I`m trying to do now: when the user selects a marker, I save his selection (marker coordinates) and then all selected coordinates are sent (via ajax)
 to the server.

The received coordinates are in a format something like this:

```
array((lat1,lng1), (lat2,lng2), ...(latn,lngn))
```

From here, I want to return back to the user all those coordinates ordered by "shortest path" and I don't know how to achieve this.

Any idea will be great.

Comment: An illustration could help: in its current form, your question seems to be asking for a solution to the [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=TSP), but it is not clear this is what you really need.

Comment: Yes, I think it`s a form of TSP but all my points are not stored into database table.

Comment: What exactly are you asking for, then? A detailed TSP algorithm? TSP code that you could use? Help in reformatting your points so that they could be read by such code?

Answer (score 1):

Since you say your markers are stored in a postgresql database, this material will be very useful for you: [TSP with pgRouting](http://pgrouting.org/docs/1.x/tsp.html)